# Html button width in percent in Webview

Tags: android, html, webview, android-webview

I have some html code and I load it to WebView. I need to set button width in percents (in order to not to depend on the screen resolution).

When I set button's width in percents I'm getting an error that `page cannot be loaded` butf I set it in pixels everything is okay.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style type='text/css'> 
            body{ position: relative; } 
            button { width: 50%; display: block; position: relative;  } 
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style='text-align:justify;color:white;'>
        Some text
        <br/>
        <button>Boo!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any thoughts?

**EDIT:**

The solution was found based on @Zak's advice, i.e., by calling the **js** function after the page was loaded, getting the screen width and setting it to the element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script language='javascript'> function SetWidth(){  d = document.getElementById('but'); d.style.width=screen.width/2; } </script>
    <style type='text/css'> body{ position: relative; } button { display: block; position: relative;  } </style>
    </head>

    <body style='text-align:justify;color:white;'>
        Text<br/>
        <button id='but' >Scary!</button>
        <script> window.onload=SetWidth; </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with DIVs that I need to be exactly X percent of screen resolution.  The way I accomplished this was using JQuery after the page has loaded, because JQuery can detect exact screen width, then you can do the math, and set a width to exactly X pixels.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var = myWidth = screen.width;
myWidth = myWidth / 2;
$('#button').width(myWidth);
});
```

I havent checked that..  But the concept uis sound I assure you

Also: Make sure this code is at the BOTTOM of the page to ensure it is rendered AFTER the page elements have loaded.